# Query to disable triggers for a particular user in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

Here is the query to disable all triggers in a particular table:

```
alter table plan_items DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

But I'm getting access issues while executing the query. How do we execute the same query passing for a particular database user? I want to delete triggers that are only part of the mentioned database user.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a user so that ordinary triggers won't fire for it:

```
ALTER ROLE myuser SET session_replication_role = replica;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
How can I rollback these changes?

Comment: And how can we restrict this for a particular table, rather than disabling triggers for all tables?

Comment: You can undo it with `ALTER TABLE ... RESET session_replication_role;`. I don't think you can disable triggers only for one user and table.

Comment: When we do `ALTER ROLE myuser SET session_replication_role = replica;`, isn't the case where we disable triggers for all tables? In that case, how do we rollback changes in all tables? we need to manually hit `alter table` query for all tables?

Comment: This has nothing to do with rollback. `ROLLBACK` will work as always, no matter if the triggers fire or not.

Comment: sorry, I mean how to undo change for all tables. Do we need to hit `alter table` for all tables separately ? Because `ALTER ROLE myuser SET session_replication_role = replica;` is applied to all table triggers.

Comment: No, it is applied to a single user. Undo it, and triggers will fire again for that user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223146/discussion-between-rahul-raj-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: This is finally what I've been searching for. I kept trying SET without the role and it would never work. This works perfect thanks!

Comment: To answer how to undo it it's ALTER ROLE myuser SET session_replication_role = origin;

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the below query does the exact job:

`ALTER TABLE table DISABLE TRIGGER USER;`

This will disable normal triggers added by the database user.